# ngIf slows down application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I created a kind of TabControl, in which I activate Pages and depending on the PageNumber I show a table  (ng-repeats). This table is an own directive (a selfmade Grid-Directive).

Now I experience, that if I have less tabpages, the application is faster than if I have more tabpages - although all pages use ngIf and are not rendered until the according PageNumber is set.

I believe, it is because ngIf Compiles it's content eventhough it shouldn't but I can't quite get to the point of it when using a profiler. I just see, that "compileNodes" gets called a lot.

Does anyone experience the same? Is there an idea for a workaround?

**Edit:**
what's also interesting is, that the first time I go to the tabcontroll (link inside a single-page-application) it's faster and the following times it's slower. As if something is remembered although the whole tabbed-control gets deleted when navigated to another content.

**Edit 2:**
I'm still trying to figure it out. It could even be the ngRepeat as I'm showing my TabControl inside another TabControl which I do with ngRepeat. Interestingly enough: The first time I visit my Page it is fast, then I click to another Page and when I come back it is slow! Does ngRepeat keep some things in cache?? The Browser-Profile tells me that there are some things in jQuery's data_user -> cache which aren't free'd (in Chrome up to 9MB of Data on every click!!)

Comment: have you tried using batarang for preformance counter? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Comment: you have every single page loaded into the DOM, then removed with `ng-if`s?

Comment: @Alex Choroshin: Yes I used Batarang - but it doesn't give me a hint why this takes longer than some other pages that have move bindings etc.

Comment: @user2943490: Well yes, but I don't think it is "loaded" or at least I thought ng-if doesn't load it (rather than ng-show). On the other hand I think it is "compiled" as stated in the ngIf doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: as per the docs, `ng-if` works by cloning existing DOM elements and storing them in memory. Even if the original element is removed from the DOM, you could have a large number of clones in memory. Do you have a very large number of DOM nodes?

Comment: @user2943490: yes I do but as my ngRepeat removes those ngIfs I assume that the ngIfs get destroyed. But as I wrote in Edit 2, your comment leaves me wondering if there are some leftovers... I don't know where they could be...

Answer (score 0):

Since its a tab view use `ng-switch` instead of `ng-if` because it has to run through all the cases to display the tab rather jumping to the tab to display.

Comment: This makes sense and I changed it for ng-switch but it didn't change anything in terms of performance. The expression for the case is very simple (PageNumer === 1) and not very costly. I can even leave the pages as they are (with the condition) and just remove the content (which is one elemement - my grid-directive)

Comment: @NoRyb Can you provide plunker so I can take a look?

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g23pxwh8/ unfortunately I cannot provide the "real" directive. But it's the overall problem that I have. My guess is, that angular compiles all the <my-complex-grid-directive> directives eventhough only one page is active and that makes it slow.